# Dont know how to fix: expected primary-expression before '.' token

Tags: c++, function, if-statement, compiler-errors

I'm currently just starting off coding in c++, the current project I'm working on is making an in-console chess engine type thing. The function below is supposed to check if a particular square has a piece on it, and if so, if the piece is white. `Board.grid` is a 2D array of strings where `"   "` would be an empty square, `"wR1"` one of the white rooks, `"bQ1"` the black queen, etcetera. I got the error `expected primary-expression before '.' token` on both if statements inside the functions and think it's got to do with the `.at()` function called on the 'square string', but have no clue why this would give an error or what could be done to resolve it.

I would appreciate it greatly if anyone could help me with this. Thanks in advance!

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct Board {
    string Grid[8][8] =
    {
        {"bR1", "bN1", "bB1", "bQ1", "bK1", "bB2", "bN2", "bR2"},
        {"bp1", "bp2", "bp3", "bp4", "bp5", "bp6", "bp7", "bp8"},
        {"   ", "   ", "   ", "   ", "   ", "   ", "   ", "   "},
        {"   ", "   ", "   ", "   ", "   ", "   ", "   ", "   "},
        {"   ", "   ", "   ", "   ", "   ", "   ", "   ", "   "},
        {"   ", "   ", "   ", "   ", "   ", "   ", "   ", "   "},
        {"wp1", "wp2", "wp3", "wp4", "wp5", "wp6", "wp7", "wp8"},
        {"wR1", "wN1", "wB1", "wQ1", "wK1", "wB2", "wN2", "wR2"},
    };
};


class Piece
    {
    public:
        bool getSquare (int square[2])
        {
            bool isOccupied = false;
            bool isWhite = false;
            if (Board.grid[square[1]][square[0]].at(0) != ' '){isOccupied = true;};
            if (Board.grid[square[1]][square[0]].at(0) == 'w'){isWhite = true;};
            bool arr[2] = {isOccupied, isWhite};
            return arr;
        };

    };
```

Comment: [mcve] would replace many words, that are meanwhile useless, since don't disclose the useful information.

Comment: `Board` isn’t defined.

Comment: `bool arr[2] = ...` and `return arr;` doesn't make any sense in the function shown.

Comment: As a ***guess*** about your error, `Board.grid[square[1]][square[0]]` isn't an object with an `at` member function. But since we don't know what `Board` or `Board.grid` might be, that's only a guess.

Comment: @JordvanEldik — that could be enough for your code, but it’s  not enough for a reproducible example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The symbol `Board` is a *type* not an instance. In C++ you can't use the `.` operator to access type members, only members of objects.

The simple solution is to create a `Board` objects:

```
struct /* Anonymous structure */ {
    string Grid[8][8] =
    {
        {"bR1", "bN1", "bB1", "bQ1", "bK1", "bB2", "bN2", "bR2"},
        {"bp1", "bp2", "bp3", "bp4", "bp5", "bp6", "bp7", "bp8"},
        {"   ", "   ", "   ", "   ", "   ", "   ", "   ", "   "},
        {"   ", "   ", "   ", "   ", "   ", "   ", "   ", "   "},
        {"   ", "   ", "   ", "   ", "   ", "   ", "   ", "   "},
        {"   ", "   ", "   ", "   ", "   ", "   ", "   ", "   "},
        {"wp1", "wp2", "wp3", "wp4", "wp5", "wp6", "wp7", "wp8"},
        {"wR1", "wN1", "wB1", "wQ1", "wK1", "wB2", "wN2", "wR2"},
    };
} Board;  // Define the Board structure object instance
```

Or possibly define `Board` as a namespace, and use the scope operator:

```
namespace Board {
    string Grid[8][8] =
    {
        {"bR1", "bN1", "bB1", "bQ1", "bK1", "bB2", "bN2", "bR2"},
        {"bp1", "bp2", "bp3", "bp4", "bp5", "bp6", "bp7", "bp8"},
        {"   ", "   ", "   ", "   ", "   ", "   ", "   ", "   "},
        {"   ", "   ", "   ", "   ", "   ", "   ", "   ", "   "},
        {"   ", "   ", "   ", "   ", "   ", "   ", "   ", "   "},
        {"   ", "   ", "   ", "   ", "   ", "   ", "   ", "   "},
        {"wp1", "wp2", "wp3", "wp4", "wp5", "wp6", "wp7", "wp8"},
        {"wR1", "wN1", "wB1", "wQ1", "wK1", "wB2", "wN2", "wR2"},
    };
}

// ...

Board::grid[square[1]][square[0]].at(0)
//   ^^
// Note use of scope operator :: here
```